# I have 2 domains one main, one parked. I recently switched but host provider told me theyd repoint the DNS but there are problems? Do it via DS

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I wanted to switch my site from `www.mutantspace.ie` to [www.mutantspace.com](http://www.mutantspace.com). Up until now the `.com` was my parked domain. I looked into it and was told that using this code in my *.htaccess* file in `www.mutantspace.ie` would work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.mutantspace.ie$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mutantspace.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]
```

I then asked my provider and he said 'Where are you moving too though?' Then he told me best way was for them to repoint site to `www.mutantspace.com`.
I said fine (in my ignorance) and that is whats happened.

However even though new URLs are being indexed I have 100s of old URLs out there returning 404s. Now I can't access my old *.htaccess* file to put in permanent redirects because its now `.com`. Is there any code that I can use anywhere in my root directory that will redirect old `www.mutantspace.ie` pages to their corresponding `www.mutantspace.com/` pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you had one hosting account for the `.ie` domain, then simply pointing the `.com` to the same hosting would be the simplest, to avoid having to move/upload files. Then set the `.ie` domain to redirect to the `.com`.

It sounds like your host did the first part, but have ignored the `.ie` domain. Depending on where the domain is held, you should be able to set up a redirect to the `.com`. Some domain providers do this well, redirecting the domain and all sub pages with a 301 redirect. Other providers only redirect the root domain, or redirect all requests from one domain to a single domain (i.e. a URL like `example.ie/page` goes to `example.com` - this is not what you want).

Alternatively, point both domains to the same hosting and use the `.htaccess` as above to do the redirecting.